# Keep only last two rows for grouped columns in table

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-delete, sqlperformance

I have a table "History" with about 300.000 rows, which is filled with new data daily. I want to keep only the last two lines of every refSchema/refId combination.

Actually I go this way:

**First Step:**

```
SELECT refSchema,refId FROM History GROUP BY refSchema,refId
```

With this statement I get all combinations (which are about 40.000).

**Second Step:**

I run a foreach which looks up for the existing rows for the query above like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM History
WHERE refSchema = ? AND refId = ? AND state = 'done'
ORDER BY importedAt 
DESC LIMIT 2,2000
```

Please keep in mind, that I want to hold the last two rows in my table, so I limit 2,2000. If I find matching rows I put the **id**'s in an array called idList.

**Final Step**

I delete all id's from the array in that way:

```
DELETE FROM History WHERE id in ($idList)
```

This all seems not to be the best performance, because I have to check every combination with an extra query. Is there a way to have one delete statement that does the magic to avoid the 40.000 extra queries?

**Edit Update:** I use AWS Aurora DB

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then one conceptually simple way to proceed here is to use a CTE to identify the top two rows per group which you do want to retain.  Then, delete any record whose schema/id pair do *not* appear in this whitelist:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT refSchema, refId
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY refSchema, refId ORDER BY importedAt DESC) rn
        FROM History
    ) t
    WHERE rn IN (1, 2)
)

DELETE
FROM History
WHERE (refSchema, refId) NOT IN (SELECT refSchema, refId FROM cte);
```

If you can't use CTE, then try inlining the above CTE:

```
DELETE
FROM History
WHERE (refSchema, refId) NOT IN (
    SELECT refSchema, refId
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY refSchema, refId ORDER BY importedAt DESC) rn
        FROM History
    ) t
    WHERE rn IN (1, 2)
);
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly we use AWS Aurora here... so it's not possible to use CTE there

Comment: @Marco Then just try inlining the CTE directly in the delete query.

Comment: It's not allowed to do a DELETE in a subquery on the same table like DELETE FROM History WHERE id in (SELECT id from History WHERE ...)

Comment: @Marco Yes it is, if you wrap the subquery in another subquery, as I have done above.  If you really are getting an error message, then paste that here, and I can try editing my answer.

Comment: I get the following error: SQL Fehler (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY refSchema, refId ORDER BY importedAt DESC) rn
        FROM Histor' at line 7